# CSS positioning error with floats?

Tags: html, css

I've ran into an issue where I have two containers and I'd like them to be side by side but whenever I insert another of the `float:left` container it gets "knocked down"...

I don't know how to solve this...

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div id="news_container">
        <div id="title_container">
            <p class="news_title">Hello World</p>
        </div>
        <p class="news_content">

        ...

       </p>
    </div>
    <div id="news_container">
        <div id="title_container">
            <p class="news_title">Hello World</p>
        </div>
        <p class="news_content">

        ...

       </p>
    </div>
    <div id="info_container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#news_container {
    width:68%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:0.083%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    background:#333;
}
    #title_container {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border-bottom:solid 1px #222;
    }
        p.news_title {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            font-size:24px;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        }
        p.news_content {
            font-size:12px;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        }
    a.news_link {
            font-size:12px;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
            text-decoration:none;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
#info_container {
    width:27.917%;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    background:#333;
}
```

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: Can you give us the HTML?

Comment: @Jaxon o right, yeah sorry

Comment: @user2615302 - no, as the 100% gets matched with the width of the parent element/div. so it gets set to 68%?

Comment: you are right try to nock it down to #title_container {
        width:95%;

Comment: @user2615302 the same issue still happens :S

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because your `news_container` has `width: 100%`. If you want to put 2 divs side by side set `width: 50%` (3 divs : `33.33%`...).  http://jsfiddle.net/ZfM6w/2/

If the number of divs is not fixed, you can use overflow or javascript.

Comment: it doesn't though, the total for `news_container` is `70.083%` and `info_container` is `29.917%`

Answer (score 0):

Never use float for such purposes. Simple use `display: table-cell` property of CSS.
Here is the code.

```
<div style="background-color: red;display:table-cell">
Box A
</div>
<div style="background-color: green;display:table-cell">
Box B
</div>
```